# Doxygen java interfaces & abstract classes

Tags: java, inheritance, uml, doxygen, diagram

I've been testing doxygen on several of my projects recently.

It seems that doxygen treat java interface, abstract class and class the same.

There's no italic font or  to suggest the type of the item. Which makes the inheritance graph looks like one class inherits from multiple super classes. Which is quite annoying.

Am I missing some setting or is it designed that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is missing feature really.

Doxygen internally knows the type, but if I remember correctly there are/were some issues with Graphviz/dot that prevented rendering some nodes with italics and others not.

There is also a long standing idea to present the classes and interfaces (and other special compound types such as Objective-C protocols and categories) in different lists, but this hasn't been implemented so far (feel free to help though ;-)